# Getting error in converting a corpus to DocumentTermMatrix in R

Tags: r, text-mining

After I preprocessed my `df_corpus` and tried to convert the cleaned corpus to a `TermDocumentMatrix`, I keep getting this error:

```
feedbacks_tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(df_corpus)
```

> Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) : 
>    no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. How exactly did you pre-process your data? `TermDocumentMatrix` expects a corpus but someone you've turned your corpus in to a character object (but you didn't include the relevant code in your question).

Comment: Thank you, i think my problem got solved after i added this line: survey<-data.frame(doc_id = row.names(survey),text = survey$text)